# Use arbitrary LaTeX itemize in Org Mode

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

If I want to export a itemized list from Org to LaTeX, is there a way to set arbitrary itemization? The usual Org plain list, i.e. `- item` will result in an `\begin{itemize}` environment, but I would like to set arbitrary itemization. For example, is there any kind of Org list markup that will output this kind of LaTeX list environment?

```
\begin{itemize}

\item[2013]
    This item happened in 2013

\item[2012]
    This item happened in 2012

\end{itemize}
```

**Edit:**

The problem is that Org is recognising the years as inactive timestamps or footnote references and this is screwing up the LaTeX export. Solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following fniessen's suggestion below I found the solution to produce an `itemize` environment without having the years turn into inactive timestamps or footnote references. The key is to insert or surround the year with spaces, which will be ignored by the TeX conversion.

```
- [ 2013 ] This item happened in 2013
- [ 2012 ] This item happened in 2012
```

If there is a more official way to do this I'd like to here it.

The other answers provide great solutions for creating both `enumerate` and `description` environments, but it was specifically `itemize` I was after.

Comment: this didn't work for me. I got `\item\relax [ 2013 ]` -- not at all what is intended

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell whether it's what you're looking for, but

```
 - 2013 :: This happened in 2013
 - 2012 :: This happened in 2012
```

will produce

```
\begin{description}
\item[2013] This happened in 2013
\item[2012] This happened in 2012
\end{description}
```

I haven't tried, but according to [this WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Description) it seems as though there will be no dot trailing the year.

Comment: This will produce a `description` environment instead of an `itemize` but it's quite useful also so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use something such as:

```
1. [@2013] This item happened in 2013
2. [@2012] This item happened in 2012
```

Comment: This will produce an `enumerate` environment instead of an `itemize` but it set me on the right path to figuring it out. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution appointed by the [org-mode manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html) is `::`, so:

```
Important actors in this film are:
   - Elijah Wood :: He plays Frodo
   - Sean Astin :: He plays Sam, Frodo's friend.
```

by the way, `[ text ]` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If as me you don't like the decription style with "- ::" syntax (that produces weird latex export) a workaround is simply to use

```
- @@latex:[2013]@@ This item happened in 2013
- @@latex:[2012]@@ This item happened in 2012
```

and, more generally,

```
- @@latex:[yourcustomitem]@@ blah blah
```